# Matching string exactly from a list of similar strings in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file which has following lines

```
1.39.2.1    Build 001

1.39.1.2    Build 002

1.39.1.1    Rejected Build

1.39        Succesful Build 004
```

and i am trying to print the line "1.39     Succesful Build 004 "
Below is my perl script

```
my $file = 'C:\labels.txt';

open(FILE,$file) or die ("Cannot the open the file : $file");

my $ver = "1.39";

my @arr;

foreach (FILE)
{

    if($_  =~ m/1.39/)
    {
        print $line;

    }

}

close(FILE);
```

When i run this script, it prints all the lines (including 1.39.x.x) . But i want the line which has exactly 1.39 . How can search for it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried using ($_  =~ m/^1.39$/), in this case  no line is printed.

Comment: It won't work as `^1.39$` will try to look for line which has 1 at start and 9 at the end. You don't have such lines.

Comment: If you want `1.39` from `1.39.2.1`, you need to capture them in your regex.  `if($_  =~ m/(1.39)/)` The result would be in `$1`.

Comment: ThanQ all for ur time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the not match the other lines, use a space after `1.39` like so:

```
/^1.39\s/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA1dB9/1)

Comment: Need `^` too to avoid matching `11.39` or `1.39.1.39`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to match line which says build is successful.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while(<DATA>){
    next if $_ =~ /^\s*$/; #skip empty lines
    my ($build, @status) = split /\s+/;
    print $_ if join(",", @status) =~ /Succesful/;
    #you may modify the above regex based on your requirement
    #I tried to match line which says build is successful
    #See dawg's answer, he matched exact build 1.39
}
__DATA__
1.39.2.1    Build 001

1.39.1.2    Build 002

1.39.1.1    Rejected Build

1.39        Succesful Build 004
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/VSwxJn)

Answer (score 1):

No-one has yet taken the time to explain why your existing code doesn't work. I think it is because you're slightly confused as to how regular expressions work.

A text string will match a regular expression if the regular expression pattern matches anywhere in the string.

Your regular expression is `/1.39/`. Actually, there's a small problem there as a dot has a special meaning in a regular expression (it matches any character) so to match an actual dot you need to escape it and your regex becomes `/1\.39/`.

Ok, so now your regex asks the question "does this string contain the substring "1.39". And, of course, all of your data lines contain that substring. For example, the line `1.39.2.1    Build 001` contains "1.39" - it's there right at the start. Sure, it's followed by other stuff, but the regex match doesn't care about that. The regex match just asks "does this string contain this substring?"

So you need to be more precise in your regex. You need to match "1.39" on its own, with nothing before it on the line and only whitespace after it. That's where the other answers come in. You can put `^` at the start of your regex to match the start of the line and `\s` at the end to match whitespace. So your regex becomes `/^1\.39\s/`.